# Do I need to specify virtual on the sub-classes methods as well?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-destructor

This has probably been asked before on SO, but I was unable to find a similar question.

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class BritneySpears
{
  public:

    virtual ~BritneySpears();
};

class Daughter1 : public BritneySpears
{
  public:

    virtual ~Daughter1(); // Virtual specifier
};

class Daughter2 : public BritneySpears
{
  public:

    ~Daughter2(); // No virtual specifier
};
```

Is there a difference between `Daughter1` and `Daughter2` classes ?

What are the consequences of specifying/not specifying `virtual` on a sub-class destructor/method ?

Comment: Note to readers: also take a look at the [`override`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880205/override-in-c11) keyword in C++11 which is closely related to that topic.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No you technically do not need to specify `virtual`. If the base member function is virtual then C++ will automatically make the matching override member function `virtual`.

However you should be marking them `override`, which ensures that it's `virtual`, and also that it overrides a member function in the base class. The method is `virtual` after all, and it makes your code much clearer and easier to follow by other developers.

---

*Note: prior to C++11, you could make the overriding member function just `virtual`, since `override` isn't available yet.*

Comment: Many good answers here. I choosed the most popular :) Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 10):

You do not need it, but marking it so may make your code clearer.

> Note: if your base class has a `virtual`
> destructor, then your destructor is
> automatically `virtual`. You might need
> an explicit destructor for other
> reasons, but there's no need to
> redeclare a destructor simply to make
> sure it is `virtual`. No matter whether
> you declare it with the `virtual`
> keyword, declare it without the
> `virtual` keyword, or don't declare it
> at all, it's still `virtual`.

- [C++ FAQ - When should my destructor be virtual?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-dtors)

Answer (score 7):

Virtual is automatically picked up on derived method overrides regardless of whether you specify it in the child class.

The main consequence is that without specifying virtual in the child it's harder to see from the child class definition that the method is in fact virtual. For this reason I always specify virtual in both parent and child classes.