# Are there any subtleties in using both the virtual and override keywords in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it dangerous to use both `virtual` and `override` on a function in C++? Does that open you up for ambiguity with overloading?

Obviously `virtual` must be used in the base class and it would be silly to not use `override` in the derived class, but is it actually problematic to use `virtual` *with* `override` in the derived class?

Trying to determine if this is an issue of style or correctness.

Example:

```
class Widget {
  virtual void transmogrify() = 0;
}

class Gadget : public Widget {
  virtual void transmogrify() override {}
}
```

Comment: You might find your answer here [\`override\` in c++11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880205/override-in-c11)

Comment: Also see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Comment: Overloading doesn't come into it. Both keywords only apply to over-riding.

Comment: @EJP - One thing the override keyword buys you is protection from accidentally overloading instead of overriding. If I had a function in my base class that took an int argument and in my derived class I have a function with the same name but it takes a double, things get interesting. `override` protects you from such confusion. If you declared the dervied class' function `virtual` (and not `override`), that simply declares a new virtual function, oops.

Comment: @Mark I'm aware of that. I was referring to your query 'does that open you up for ambiguity with overloading?'

Comment: @Mark: But "new virtual function" does not overload, it hides.  To overload, you'd need an overrider or using statement for the existing function, plus a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late to the game, but [this C++ Core Guideline](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override) seems relevant here:

> #### C.128: Virtual functions should specify exactly one of `virtual`, `override`, or `final`
>
> **Reason**
>
> Readability. Detection of mistakes. Writing explicit `virtual`, `override`, or `final` is self-documenting and enables the compiler to catch mismatch of types and/or names between base and derived classes. However, writing more than one of these three is both redundant and a potential source of errors.
>
> It's simple and clear:
>
> - `virtual` means exactly and only "this is a new virtual function."
> - `override` means exactly and only "this is a non-final overrider."
> - `final` means exactly and only "this is a final overrider."

Comment: "virtual means exactly and only this is a new virtual function." is a style convention -- it does not mean that to the compiler

Answer (score 35):

The `virtual` keyword has no effect when you are overriding.  A derived function that is a signature match for a virtual function defined in a base class will override the base definition, and the override will be entered in the vtable, whether the `virtual` keyword is used in the derived class or not.

Because the `override` keyword will cause a compile error if overriding is not happening, the `virtual` keyword is useless in combination.

Here, have a cheatsheet:

```
| Keyword used | Matching virtual function in base class | Result                   |
|--------------|-----------------------------------------|--------------------------|
| Neither      | No                                      | New non-virtual function |
| Neither      | Yes                                     | Override                 |
| virtual      | No                                      | New virtual function     |
| virtual      | Yes                                     | Override                 |
| override     | No                                      | Compile error            |
| override     | Yes                                     | Override                 |
| Both         | No                                      | Compile error            |
| Both         | Yes                                     | Override                 |
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are saying two different, but important things about `Gadget`'s method `transmogrify`

`virtual` - if a class derives from `Gadget` then the `transmogrify` function will be treated as virtual by the derived class

`override` - the `Gadget` class is explicitly overriding the base class `Widget`'s version of `transmogrify`.

The two key works are orthogonal and do not affect one another. The nice thing about the `override` keyword is that it is stating to the compiler that you are attempting to override an inherited virtual function. If you made a mistake in matching the function signature of the function on the base class it won't compile as it *must* override an inherited function if declared as an `override`

Comment: Point one was ensured by `Widget`, `Gadget` has no say in the matter, and certainly the appearance of the `virtual` keyword in `Gadget` makes no difference.