# finding close member function names in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

I just had a bug (of my own making!) which manifested as follows.  I had class with a virtual member function which I needed to extend by adding an extra parameter for some new use cases.  I added it, with default values, such that it didn't break any current calls.  What I missed was that there was another class which inherited from this class which had an override of this function that was no longer an override.  While I'm aware of the [override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880205/is-the-override-keyword-just-a-check-for-a-overridden-virtual-method) keyword to avoid this when adding new code, I was wondering is there any way of finding all functions that are lexically close enough to be possible cases of a similar bug.  Having done this once there is a possibility that I may have done it at some time in the past and would like to retrospectively check the code base.

Comment: I am not aware of anything like that, in any C++ compiler.

Comment: I used to use Lint for this type of thing many years ago, but had thought the compilers did most of that type of checking by now.  Maybe not...

Comment: I do not recall lint making any kind of lexical comparison analysis. Current versions of gcc do sort-of do something when complaining about some undeclared identifier -- gcc will try to find something, somewhere, that has a similar name and include "maybe you meant that" in an error message. But, gcc won't proactively warn you about it. Even small C++ programs inherit a boatload of identifiers as soon as any std header gets included, so doing this kind of a check would slow down compilation even more.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: clang has warning for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang has warning flag `-Woverloaded-virtual`

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void foo(int = 42) {}
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void foo() {} // Oups
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0bfdfcf00123f7)

You might also be interested by clang-tidy with [modernize-use-override](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-override.html), to add `override` and avoid this mistake in any C++11 compliant compiler in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this, just installed llvm and clang on VS2017 and while it runs ok on small sample projects, a number of third party libraries I'm using on my main program fail to compile.  I'll look at the settings in more detail later on to see if I can figure a workaround.