# Inheritance polymorphism for subclasses of subclasses in c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class parent {
   public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "parent::f2()" << endl; }
};

class child : public parent {
   public:
    void f() { cout << "child::f()" << endl; }
};

class grandchild : public child {
   public:
    void f() { cout << "grandchild::f()" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    grandchild grandchild1;
    parent *p = &grandchild1;
    p->f();
}
```

The above code runs like this

```
grandchild::f()
```

In class `child`, I didn't define `f()` as a virtual function. Why does `p->f()` still call the `f()` in class `grandchild`?

Comment: Once a function is declared `virtual`, it will be `virtual` in all derived classes.

Comment: `p` is a pointer to `parent` and in `parent` the method is already decalred virtual. Its not possible for a derived class to remove the virtualness

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167045/do-i-need-to-specify-virtual-on-the-sub-classes-methods-as-well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895294/c-virtual-keyword-for-functions-in-derived-classes-is-it-necessary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024476/should-methods-that-implement-pure-virtual-methods-of-an-interface-class-be-decla/ (unfortunately, all of them are old and suggest adding `virtual` for clean code instead of `override`...)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I sometimes wonder whats the right way to deal with such questions. One could retroactively retag them as `c++03` (or whatever is appropriate). On the other hand, sometimes the uptodate answer is somewhere down the list (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4026322/4117728), and such answers would get invalidated by retagging

Comment: also this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/26375213/4117728 hidden behind lots of older answers

Comment: Side note on design : Don't confuse biological inheritance with class inheritance. In fact you probably should have only one class `class Human`. And model Parent/Child as relations. Object oriented doesn't mean use inheritance for everything.

Comment: Another side note: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)…

Comment: Yet another side note: If a function is virtual in the base class then a function with the same signature in a deriving class *overrides* it – it is a good idea to mark such functions with `override` keyword: It makes obvious what actually is going on, but more important it makes compilation fail on mismatching signatures (mixed up parameter types, forgotten parameters, ... – or because the base class interface changed).

Comment: @PepjinKramer I wonder where the parent-child analogy for inheritance originates from. Imho it couldnt be more confusing for beginners. I mean, in what world there is a is-a relation between the child and its parent? A new born child is a parent!?

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++20 Standard ([Virtual functions [class.virtual]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.virtual#1))

> [**1**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.virtual#1) **A non-static member function is a *virtual function* if it is first
> declared with the keyword `virtual`** or if it overrides a virtual
> member function declared in a base class (see below).

and

> [**2**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.virtual#2) If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a
> class `Derived`, **derived directly or indirectly from `Base`**, a member
> function `vf` with the same name, *parameter-type-list* ([[dcl.fct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.fct)),
> *cv-qualification*, and *ref-qualifier* (or absence of same) as `Base::vf`
> is declared, then `Derived::vf` overrides<sup>113</sup> `Base::vf`.

Pay attention to that even a virtual function can be hidden in some intermediate derived class nevertheless it can be overriden in a subsequent derived class.

That is if for example you will change your classes the following way

```
class parent
{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "parent::f()" << endl; }
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    void f( int ) { cout << "child::f()" << endl; }
};

class grandchild : public child
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "grandchild::f()" << endl; }
};
```

where the function `f( int )` declared in the class `child` hides the virtual function `f()` declared in the class `parent` nevertheless you can override it in the class `grandchild`. The program output wll be the same as in the original program.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class parent
{
public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "parent::f()" << endl; }
};

class child : public parent
{
public:
    void f( int = 0 ) { cout << "child::f( int )" << endl; }
};

class grandchild : public child
{
public:
    void f() { cout << "grandchild::f()" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    grandchild grandchild1;
    parent *p = &grandchild1;
    p->f(); 

    child child1;
    p = &child1;
    p->f();
}
```

The program output is

```
grandchild::f()
parent::f()
```

Some remarks. For the class `child` the final overrider of the virtual function, declared in the class `parent`, is the function `parent::f`. For the class `grandchild` the final overrider is the function `grandchild::f`.

It is better to use always the specifier `override` in declarations of virtual functions as for example

```
class grandchild : public child
{
public:
    void f() override { cout << "grandchild::f()" << endl; }
};
```

In this case your code will be more clear.